# Holomorphic implies Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I'm making some notes on minimal surfaces and i was reading my old notes on my course on Complex analysis on one variable and i noticed the following in the prove that (real and imaginary parts of) holomorphic functions satisfies the C-R equations. When doing $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}=\lim_{l\to 0}\frac{u\left((x_0,y_0)+l(1,0)\right)-u(x_0,y_0)+iv\left((x_0,y_0)+l(1,0)\right)-iv(x_0,y_0)}{l}=u_x(x_0,y_0)+iv_x(x_0,y_0).$$ (maybe is a stupid question) we use that the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits, but its not true in general that if the limit of sum exists, then exists the limit of each summand. What I'm missing here

Comment: Limit of a complex-valued (or more generally vector-valued) function exists if and only if the real and imaginary parts (resp. each component) have limits. So, here it’s not the limit and sum rule being used, but rather complex-valued limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $\mathcal{Re} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ that return the real part of a complex number. Such function is continuous. Indeed for each $\epsilon>0$ you can choose $\delta=\epsilon$ and if $\|z-z_0\|< \delta$ you will have
$$
|\mathcal{Re}(z)-\mathcal{Re}(z_0)| \le \|z-z_0\| <\delta=\epsilon
$$
Similarly $\mathcal{Im} : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

so if $\lim_{ z \to z_0} f(z)$ exists you have that

$$
\lim_{z \to z_0} \mathcal{Re}(f(z))=\mathcal{Re} \left(\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z) \right)
$$
and so the limit of the real part exists. Same for the limit of the imaginary part. Now that you know that the two limits exist you can use that sum of limits is equal to limits of sum